# adapter is null when calling notifyDataSetChanged() onResume()

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter

I have a fragment that contains a listView that i want to be updated whenever a new record is added. Im trying to call .notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume() in fragment but the adapter = null.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log,
            container, false);

    exmaplePrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    json = exmaplePrefs.getString("jsonString", "cant find json");

    JSONObject MainObj = null;
    JSONArray JsonArray = null;

    try {

        MainObj = new JSONObject(json);
        JsonArray = MainObj.getJSONArray("Events");

            for(int i = 0; i < JsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = JsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
               String time = c.getString("time");
               String event = c.getString("event");
               String player = c.getString("player");   

               String from[] = {"time","event", "player"};
               int to[] = {R.id.time,R.id.event, R.id.player};

                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("time", time);
                map.put("event", event);
                map.put("player",player);
                newItemlist.add(map);
                listV=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), newItemlist, R.layout.custom_list_row, from, to);
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.print("ERROR");
    }

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("worked");

    if (adapter != null){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    }
}
```

I think this is something to do with the adapter being created onCreateView() and is not visible when I return to the Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this, I see a few problems.

1. It's generally very poor practice to `catch ( Exception ex)`. Try catching only the specific Exceptions you are worried about, it makes fixing problems easier.
2. Why is your ArrayAdapter created inside of a for loop? You probably wand something like this:

   ```
   ArrayList list=new ArrayList(); //Specify what type of value is in the ArrayAdapter
   adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), newItemlist, R.layout.custom_list_row,list);
   listV.setAdapter(adapter);
   MainObj = new JSONObject(json);
   JsonArray = MainObj.getJSONArray("Events");

   for(int i = 0; i < JsonArray.length(); i++){
       JSONObject c = JsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

       // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
      String time = c.getString("time");
      String event = c.getString("event");
      String player = c.getString("player");   

      String from[] = {"time","event", "player"};
      int to[] = {R.id.time,R.id.event, R.id.player};

       // Adding value HashMap key => value
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map.put("time", time);
       map.put("event", event);
       map.put("player",player);
       newItemlist.add(map);
       listV=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
       adapter.add(map);
   }
   ```

I'm not quite sure what SimpleArrayAdapter is, but you want to create a new one once outside of the loop, and add things to it inside of the loop most likely, re-creating it seems like a poor choice. You'll probably need to do some playing with the `adapter.add(map)` command in particular, but this general pattern should help. You'll also need to change the `ArrayList list` to something like `ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>()`, to whatever your ArrayAdapter is storing (Looks like `HashMap<String,String>`)

Comment: I have made some changes as you suggested an the adapter is no longer null... But, it only contains data if onCreateView() is called. i.e. newItemlist

Comment: Look carefully at the lifecycle of a Fragment, and decide at which point you need to initialize the arrayAdapter. Then initialize it there.

Answer (score 1):

If an `Exception` is thrown, you will directly move to the `catch` block, hence skipping `adapter`'s initialization. This probably means that there is an error parsing your JSON string.

Comment: i have tested this, it never hits the exception

Comment: if orientation is changed the adapter is updated as onCreateView() is called again. I want this to happen automatically